# In Yodlee webservices, how to get a list of cobrand-specific user accounts?

Tags: yodlee

I have developer cobrand account calling rest services on 1-5 test user accounts (created as part of my dev act). My question, how can I get a list of all accounts (preferable id's would be returned as well) associated with my cobrand (ie: as of now: the 5 test accounts) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the list of accounts added for each of those 5 test users under your cobrand then, you will need to call [getAllSiteAccounts](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) and then [getItemSummariesForSite](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesForSite) for each of those test users.

If you want list of users registered on Yodlee platform under your cobrand ,then currently there is no API to get that list. You will have to save the list of registered users on Yodlee's platform for your cobrand at your end.